# how to created nested javascript object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object

This works just fine in chrome/firefox, but fails in IE 9.  How can I do this correctly?

```
var Wrapper = function ()
{
  this.loc = {};
  this.loc.default = {};   // fails here in IE
  this.loc.default.lat = 30;
  this.loc.default.lon = -120;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words
maybe it is due to that `default` is reserved keyword in JS

did you try with another instead of `default`

Answer (score 0):

[`default` is a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). Try calling it something else.